# Confused in pointers of two dimensional struct

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

I am creating a dynamic structure using malloc. My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct
    {
        int v=;
        int t;
        struct a *prev;//points to previous struct in same row
        struct a *next;//points to next struct in same row
        //Is this correct notation?
    } a;
    a **b;
```

During initialization, I do this:

```
for(i=0;i<d1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<d2;j++)
        {
            if (j==0) //if first block, point to NULL
                b[i][j]->prev = NULL;
            else //else point to previous block.
                b[i][j]->prev = *(b[i] + j - sizeof(b[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

I am getting error invalid type argument. What is wrong here? For prev, I am trying to first find address of the current block `*(b[i]+j)` and to get address of previous block, subtracting the size of each block i.e. `sizeof(b[i][j])`

Comment: Adding `n` to a typed pointer `T * p;` lets the pointer's value increase by `n * sizeof (T)` bytes.

Comment: There is no type `struct a` in the code shown so far.

Comment: When you have compiler or linker errors, specify the exact error messages. Also, `int v=;`?

Comment: You need `typedef struct a {` etc., in order for `struct a *prev;` to mean a pointer to this struct.  Un-tagged struct is different type to `struct a`.

Answer (score 1):

`b[i][j]` is not a pointer. Hence, You cannot use:

```
b[i][j]->prev = NULL;
```

Use

```
b[i][j].prev = NULL;
```

**Update**

The links between the objects can be created using:

```
for(j=0;j<d2;j++)
{
    // Fix the prev link
    if (j==0) //if first block, point to NULL
        b[i][j].prev = NULL;
    else //else point to previous block.
        b[i][j].prev = &b[i][j-1];

     // Fix the next link
    if (j==d2-1) //if last block, point to NULL
        b[i][j].next = NULL;
    else //else point to next block.
        b[i][j].next = &b[i][j+1];
```

}

Comment: Compiler says, incompatible types while assigning (in the second assignment)

Comment: @Maxsteel, It will be best if you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This code is as complete as it can get. It is independent of anything else in my complete code. Sorry, if you can point what's missing, I can correct it.

Comment: @Maxsteel, the posted definition of `a` is not right. It should be `typedef struct a { ... } a;`. I'm not sure whether that's tripping up your compiler.

Comment: Is the logic to get to the address of the prev block correct? I will try to change the def meanwhile.

Comment: @Maxsteel, I don't know whether that is right or wrong. It's not clear from your post how the objects in the 2D array are linked. Is any object from `b[0]` linked with any object from `b[1]`?

Comment: No, they're not. Only the structs in same row should be linked to it's previous node.

Comment: About the MCVE:  your code doesn't have a main program, and doesn't allocate space for a.  That's the way in which it isn't complete.  If you can get a version that compiles (or would compile except for that error), it will be easier to help.

Comment: Ha! It's not! :-S Your latest snippet still uses `->next/prev` but `.next/prev`.

Comment: @alk, you'd think I could follow my own suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want elements within each row to be dlinked but not against previous rows.  My take:

```
void
fill(void)
{
    int d1;
    int d2;
    a **b;
    a *x;
    int i;
    int j;

    d1 = 10;
    d2 = 20;

    b = calloc(d1 * d2,sizeof(a));

    x = &b[0][0];

    for (i=0;  i<d1;  i++) {
        x->prev = NULL;
        x->next = x + 1;
        for (x++, j=1;  j<d2;  j++, x++) {
            x->prev = x - 1;
            x->next = x + 1;
        }
        x[-1].next = NULL;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Pointer arithmetic when you add n to a pointer.  If n is 1, you are *not* adding 1 to the address, you're adding sizeof(*ptr).  Consider that all of the following are equivalent:

```
int *xp;
int n;

(A1) xp += n;
(A2) xp = (int *) (((unsigned long) xp) + (n * sizeof(int)))
(A3) xp = &xp[n];
(A4) xp = (int *) (((char *) xp) + (n * sizeof(int)))
```

Stare at this for a while until you truly understand why this is true.  This is *key*.  The value you add to a pointer should exactly equal the index value of an array of the same type.

Your code is broken in a few ways:
- You need to replace `b[i][j]->prev` with `b[i][j].prev` because `b[i][j]` already fully dereferences the pointer [*this was pointed out by others*]
- When you're doing `*(b[i] + j - sizeof(b[i][j])`, I'm not even sure what you'll get.
- You want `&b[i][j-1]` (A3).  Your code [if it works at all], probably produces `&b[i][j-18]`.
- This is because your mixing pointer arithmetic and byte sizes (e.g. you're doing a mashup of (A1), (A2), and (A3) above--you can use one or the other but not both/all at the same time)

My code only needs a single pointer that is set at the beginning because it's incremented by 1 in the inner loop.
Note that after finishing the "j loop", `x == &b[i][d2]` which is also `&b[i+1][0]`.  That might help make it clearer.
Also, I handle the j==0 case before the inner j loop and post fix the "j==d2-1" case afterwards.  That way, no if's inside the inner loop and why it starts at 1, not 0
Note that `x[-1].next` (case A3) is `(x - 1)->next` (case A1)

Here the loops are recoded slightly to be a bit simpler/faster.  It assumes an addition variable: `a *ep;`

```
for (i=0;  i<d1;  i++) {
    x->prev = NULL;
    x->next = x + 1;
    ep = x + d2;
    for (x++;  x<ep;  x++) {
        x->prev = x - 1;
        x->next = x + 1;
    }
    x[-1].next = NULL;
}
```

I think you've got enough to get your code working.  After that, try to understand your code vs mine and why both work the way they do.  Doing this will give you a leg up on dealing with pointers and pointer arithmetic and it will soon be as easy as indexing through an ordinary fixed size array.  Happy Programming ...

Comment: Am I not setting next/prev of x and not b?