# What does ARR+num*8 do? where ARR is a dynamic array and num is an int

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

ARR is an array made using malloc. Then, it is passed to a function as ARR+num*8.
what does it do or mean?

Comment: It's hard to say without any code...

Comment: Probably messing with pointers

Answer (score 1):

It means `&ARR[num*8]`.

If integer, say `n`, is added to the pointer, It will be a pointer that points `n` elements ahead of the original pointer.

> `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`

(N1256 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

Answer (score 0):

It means: `arr + (num * 8)` or `&arr[num * 8]`

See my more detailed explanation in my answer here: [Confused in pointers of two dimensional struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133175/confused-in-pointers-of-two-dimensional-struct/33134436#33134436)